# Values are null when POSTing to Razor Handler via JavaScript fetch()

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor, fetch

I'm trying to POST email content to a Razor Handler, but the request values don't seem to be properly binding. I've been scouring all I can (including many questions on SO) for answers without luck.

The code sends the data properly as best I can tell from the Network tab. My breakpoint in the handler is hit, but the request has null values. (I'm running .NET Core 3.0, for what it's worth.)

I've tried:

- adding `Content-Type` to the `fetch` headers
- adding the `[FromBody]` attribute to the request parameter
- sending the body as an object instead of serializing it
- changing `List<int>` to `int[]`
- changing my request class properties to be lowercase, camelcase, etc, just incase there was a different ContractResolver in my default SerializerSettings

My code and some screenshots are below. Any suggestions/answers appreciated.

**JS**

```
//sample data
const To = "stack@overflow.com";
const Body = "This is the email body.";
const Subject = "Hello world!";
const PortraitId = 17;
const FileIds = [1,2,3];
const body = { PortraitId, To, Subject, Body, FileIds };

const handler = "SendEmail";
const url = new URL(window.location.href.split('?')[0]);
const parameters = { handler };
url.search = new URLSearchParams(parameters).toString();

await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
  }
});
```

**C#**

```
public class SendEmailRequest
{
  public int PortraitId { get; set; }
  public string To { get; set; }
  public string Subject { get; set; }
  public string Body { get; set; }
  public List<int> FileIds { get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSendEmail(SendEmailRequest request) {
  //do stuff
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not to steer you away from `fetch` but could you use the jQuery `$.ajax(...)` POST just to test if the data gets sent to the server? I use that almost exclusively for all my POST calls; find it more flexible. Let me know if you need help with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I replicated that, added both `[FromBody]` and `"Content-Type": "application/json"`

```
([FromBody] SendEmailRequest request)
```

and

```
headers: {
   "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

And this started working properly. So if with these fixes it won't work, please to share all your `Middlewares` (or Authentication providers).

[image]

Comment: I like this option, I usually add __RequestVerificationToken to the model as well as make the framework bind using Newtonsoft as it's easier to manage
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options=>{...});

Answer (score 0):

So, model is being sent as null and the values from ajax end are being passed fine. I see, to initialize your object model you need to specify from where should the object mapper map the values. In your case, you need to specify `[FromBody]` explicitly along with your object in the parameters so it can be sure that the values are going to come from the body of the ajax call. Like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSendEmail([FromBody] SendEmailRequest request)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This will tell the object mapper to map the object of type `SendEmailRequest` from the `json` body that is being sent in the `POST` call and it will go straight to the body and pick the relevant fields and initialize the `SendEmailRequest request` object with the provided values.

Since your browser is already taking your request body as `JSON` but I would like you to explicitly tell the `ajax` call that the data you are sending is of type `json`.

```
await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset = utf-8;", // By Adding this header.
    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
  }
});
```

As I see, you already have tried the changes suggested above, so I would like to take you back to traditional ajax call. Let me know if this works for you?

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    fail: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks about right. Try to create the object in javascript as follows:

```
{
  portraitId: 1,
  to: "string",
  subject: "string"
  body: "string"
  fileIds: [1,2]
}
```

Notice that keys are `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase`.
Also be aware that this kind of "null objects" errors are almost always related to how you send the request to the backend.

I.E:
If you send this object to your back end server:

```
{
  portraitId: "string", //notice that I change the data type expected from number to string
  to: "string",
  subject: "string"
  body: "string"
  fileIds: [1,2]
}
```

the whole model binding breaks, and you get null values in your properties. Its like the controller says, "hey I accept only `THIS` model, and no other else. I wont compromise". Wich is good because we want to be sure that our data maintain some kind of consistency